# SSL Issue When Connecting to Heroku Postgres

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am having an issue connecting to a Postgres Heroku hobby dyno via a Glitch instance with Node. I've looked through posts with similar problems, but still cannot find a solution. I've tried setting an env var  in Node `PGSSLMODE="require"`
and running the code below, but I always get the same error. Thank you

```
const pg = require('pg')
const { Client } = require('pg');

pg.defaults.ssl = true
const client = new pg.Client({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: true,
});

client.connect();
```

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: self signed certificate at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1051:34)
```

Comment: welcome to stackoveflow. Take a tour and get your first badge-https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

You can't set it as `ssl:true` because that means you are self assigning your own certificate. Since you are using Heroku own PostgreSQL database you have a SSL certificate already. All you need to do is determine if you want to require or disable it.

```
const client = new Client({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  sslmode: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "require" : "disable"
})
```

I want to point out that you don't have to add sslmode because it by defaults requires the ssl certificate but just to be safe add the sslmode.